# Wrong position of text in search bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

When I tap to search bar in navigation bar title,text of textfield changing position to bottom and placeholder have alignment center. How fix it? Need native vertical center position text and placeholder of search bar.[image]

Comment: Please edit to post a photo of your problem.

Comment: @AaronZheng , updated with photo

Comment: Please, add the code you're using.

Comment: The problem you are having could be caused by numerous errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx all for answer, I solved this issue. In my case, need uncheck in storyboard Extended Edges - Under Top Bars. And I use custom views in storyboard scenes. I enable opaque navigation bars in storyboard scene and my custom view(nib file) and it work! Thx all for answers,again)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having could be caused by numerous errors.

1) 
 Scroll View insets in layout is not checked. [image: Scroll View insets]

2) If constraints are added, they could be affecting the searchTextView insets also. Remove some and check if they are a factor.

3) You have forgotten to adjust the search text offset.
[image: TextOffset]